# College Paper on Random Walk Models

Tags: statistics

I just have one question about my college thesis. I want to study about random walk models in two and three dimensions. I know what they are and I was just wondering if you know some possible sources about random walk models. Also, I have a tough time coming up a theory about random walk models in two and three dimensions. Could you possibly help me out?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: These sound like questions you should be asking a professor or advisor.

Comment: I can help you find material, my friend. You can ask your questions in chat.

Comment: You've picked the topic without sources?

Comment: Nima Bavari- Good. I have no idea what "chat" is.